# Drawing ellipse with large axes with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw slightly curved line (arc with large radius) between two points in image. To do that I use `ellipse` from OpenCV. `ellipse` has limited performance for large values (~5000) of `axes` parameter:

1. Small change (~0.1 deg) of `startAngle` parameter does not affect drawn ellipse. The drawn ellipse is updated approximately every 0.9 deg. Since `startAngle` parameter is type float I would expect much finer step change.
2. It seems like drawn ellipse is composed of straight lines. Again I would expect much finer details.

To demonstrate described behavior:

[image]

Code to reproduce:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

radius = 5000
center = (-2500, 4300)

for i in range(31):
    img = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    start_angle = -59 + i / 10

    cv2.ellipse(img, center=center, axes=(radius, radius), angle=0, startAngle=-59, endAngle=-54, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
    cv2.ellipse(img, center=center, axes=(radius, radius), angle=0, startAngle=start_angle, endAngle=-54, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1)
    cv2.putText(img, 'Start angle: {} deg'.format(start_angle), (10, 450), color=(0, 0, 255), fontScale=1, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)

    cv2.imshow('', img)
    cv2.waitKey(100)

cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Is there a way how to draw slightly curved line between two points in image which does not have above mentioned limitations?

### Edit:

Based on Christoph's Rackwitz answer I made a function for drawing arc based on `cv2.polylines`:

```
def arc(img, center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, points_count, color, thickness):
    pts = []
    for angle in np.linspace(start_angle, end_angle, points_count):
        x = int(center[0] + radius * np.cos(angle * np.pi / 180))
        y = int(center[1] + radius * np.sin(angle * np.pi / 180))

        pts.append([x, y])

    cv2.polylines(img, [np.array(pts)], isClosed=False, color=color, thickness=thickness)
```

To compare with `cv2.ellipse`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def arc(img, center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, points_count, color, thickness):
    pts = []
    for angle in np.linspace(start_angle, end_angle, points_count):
        x = int(center[0] + radius * np.cos(angle * np.pi / 180))
        y = int(center[1] + radius * np.sin(angle * np.pi / 180))

        pts.append([x, y])

    cv2.polylines(img, [np.array(pts)], isClosed=False, color=color, thickness=thickness)


radius = 5000
center = (-2500, 4300)
start_angle = -59
end_angle = -54

img = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.ellipse(img, center=center, axes=(radius, radius), angle=0, startAngle=start_angle, endAngle=end_angle, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
arc(img, center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, points_count=101, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1)

cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Method with `cv2.ellipse` (red) draw straight line and solution based on `cv2.polylines` (green) draw slightly curved line as was required.

[image]

Comment: direct enhancements to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues

Comment: well... pixels are organized in a grid, so it can technically only be composed of straight or diagonal connectsions of pixels. Maybe have a look at the "fractions" parameter, but I think it is only for subpixel accuracy of center and radius...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739261/can-the-opencv-circle-function-be-used-to-draw-a-circle-with-an-odd-diameter/57740182#57740182
and https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69

Comment: ah, have a look at the documentary: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69 there the thing with piecewise linear arcs and a trick with poly lines is explained...

Comment: @Micka You are right, shift ("fractions") parameter is for sub-pixel precision for center position and for axes length. The trick with poly lines seemed promising but parameter "delta" (which define angle between the subsequent polyline vertices) is limited to integers and a result is similar/equal to one obtained from cv2.ellipse.

Comment: maybe have a look at the source code and adapt a double precision delta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could draw a polyline and calculate the coordinates for the segments yourself.

Comment: there is a function to get arc poly points: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga727a72a3f6a625a2ae035f957c61051f