# cv2 circles not clear it look like rhombus

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

my code below draw circles on black image with 2 pixel radius ,,but it is not clear circle shape it look like rhombus,,

how I get clear circle even if it small?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((500,500,3), np.uint8)

for x in range (0,500,10):
    for y in range(0, 500, 10):
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 2,(255, 255, 255), -1)

#Display the image
cv2.imshow("img",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: picture please. and did you try line style `cv.LINE_AA` ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739261/can-the-opencv-circle-function-be-used-to-draw-a-circle-with-an-odd-diameter/57740182#57740182 try to play with that parameter.

Comment: Btw. How would you draw a circle with radius of 2 pixel? You could try resizing a bigger circle image which could give a better interpolation, but dont expect wonders in a 4x4 pixel region...

Comment: yes cv.LINE_AA is help ..  thank you christoph-rackwitz